# MSSQL Comment in Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, azure

Pardon my ignorance in database, but in MySQL, I can create a column with a comment like so:

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  ListingID int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'System ID'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

But I am transfering my MySQL database to Microsoft's Azure MSSQL one. I am trying to find out how to import columns with `COMMENT` in them.

I have looked everywhere and searched everywhere. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the comment, it's not used for anything.

Comment: @Barmar So the `COMMENT` functionality is disabled in `MSSQL`?